# how to use foreach with array object

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, buddypress

```
global $wpdb, $bp;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE value = '$_POST[language]' OR value = '$_POST[budget]' OR value = '$_POST[style]'LIMIT 0 , 30");
print_r($result);
```

The output is:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 2 )
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 2 ) 
        [2] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 2 ) 
        [3] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 4 ) )
```

I want the value as comma separated string.

Comment: it tell you that the value in the array are Object....

Comment: access for e.g. the first user_id so: $result[0]->user_id

Comment: or foreach($result as $r) { print_r($r->user_id);}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hier is a possible solution;

```
<?php 
    global $wpdb, $bp;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE 
                value = '$_POST[language]' OR value = '$_POST[budget]' 
                OR value = '$_POST[style]'LIMIT 0 , 30");
    $str_ids = '';
    foreach($result as $r) {
         $str_ids .= ('' == $str_ids) ? '' : ', ';
         $str_ids .= $r->user_id;
    }
    print_r($str_ids);
```

Comment: wow you are amazing guyes...you know i tried 5 days and get solution 30 min.what the waste i did.its works perfect but there is duplicate id how to remove it

Comment: Just replace your sql through: "SELECT DISTINCT user_id from"... And the rest. The "DISTINCT" command ist important in your case to avoid duplicate.

Comment: On the otherside the belowed answer of dianuj using get_col seems to be a good way to achieve your goals and using the "DISTINCT" command.

Answer (score 1):

`get_results()` will return an object. You can simply loop through the object and access the id using object notation, like so:

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($result as $k => $id) {
    $arr[] = $id->user_id;
}
$string = implode(',', $arr);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`get_col()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) instead:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT user_id 
FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data 
WHERE value = '$_POST[language]' OR value = '$_POST[budget]' 
OR value = '$_POST[style]'LIMIT 0 , 300");
```

And now, to get the comma-separated string, use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$string = implode(',', $result);
```

Comment: `get_row()` will return single row not all http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row

Comment: i am currently working on buddypress so i need to use get_result.

Comment: @user2810499: The first part of my answer shows how you can do it with `get_results()`. And to get the unique ids, you can do `$arr = array_unique($arr);` before the line `$string = implode(',', $arr);`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**get_col**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) of wpdb when you have to get one column

```
$result = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT user_id FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE value = '$_POST[language]' OR value = '$_POST[budget]' OR value = '$_POST[style]'LIMIT 0 , 30");

echo  implode(",",$result);
or 

echo  join(",",$result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str=implode(",",json_decode(json_encode($result),true));
```